# how to count (fast) if a value already exists in mysql column?

Tags: mysql

Currently I have a loop that I use to check each value from array.

```
foreach k, v = []array{
 "SELECT COUNT(*) from column WHERE v='$v'"
}
```

It works fine except that it's not performant. Is there any way that I can perform this query somehow in batches(e.g. like the `IN` clause) and get the result in batches too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to check if the value exists in the table:

```
SELECT 1 from column WHERE v='$v'
```

and if you want to check for multiple values then try this:

```
SELECT 1 from column WHERE v in ('$v',....)
```

Comment: how do I know which ``in`` value exist and which doesn't ? I mean how do I associate the values ( ``$v ``) with the sql rows ?